# Gradle Duplicate handling strategy Problem

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project grade.

```
root
  +---- Project A
  +---- Project B
```

Project A depends on Project B. But gradle compiles first Project A and then Project B.

My files:
settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'rootProject'
include 'projecta'
include 'projectb'
```

Project A build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':projectb')
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

When I build a get the error. But I do not know to but duplicate handling strategy

Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':projectb:distTar'.
> Entry /lib/projecta.jar is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

Comment: What's the files in the path `../lib` relative to the Project A? Are they external libraries?

Comment: Yes files in ../lib are external libraries and projecta.jar is also included as other projects also depends on this library folder

Comment: The default jar output path of A is `project_root/projecta/build/libs/`. How did you put the projecta.jar to `project_root/lib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task copyJarToLib(type: Copy) {
    if (project.name == 'projecta') {
        copy {
            from jar
            into '../lib'
            eachFile { file ->
                println 'Copying file ' + file + ' to ./lib'            
            }
        }        
    }
}

distZip.finalizedBy = [copyJarToLib]
```

But it copies the file to early. I want to copy the file when the whole module has finished

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
task copyDxComToLib(dependsOn: jar) {
    doLast {
        println '*** COPY PROJECTA.JAR TO LIB ***'
        copy {
            from '../build/projecta.jar'
            into '../lib'
            eachFile { file ->
                println '*** Copying file ' + file + ' to ./lib'
            }
        }
        
        println '*** COPY PROJECTA.JAR TO LIB ***'
    }
}

distZip.dependsOn = [copyprojectaDxComToLib]
```